# Rails - Sending a GET Request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, get, crud, google-signin

I'm trying to retrieve a user's Google account information when a form is submitted. In order to do so, I have to make a GET request to an url. Here's what it says in the YouTube API documentation

```
To request the currently logged-in user's profile, send a GET request
to the following URL. Note: For this request, you must provide an
authentication token, which enables YouTube to identify the user.

https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/default
```

https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_profiles?hl=en

How do I make it so a custom (or specificall this) GET request happens when the form is submitted, and how do I provide the authentication token? Information that might help: When the form is submitted, it will go to the VideoController's new method.

Also after making the request, how do I access the information? I need to see whether `<yt:relationship>` is present or not in the given information.

Thanks!

Comment: how do you do the GET request to google?

Comment: Yeah, that's my question.

Comment: you havent provided your code to analize

Comment: It's not really a code specific question as it's how does one make a GET request.

Comment: to make direct get/post calls use for example `excon` gem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find HTTParty gem as very useful for working with external APIs in rails.

You can make requests as

```
 response = HTTParty.post("http://www.example.com", :timeout => 5, :body => "my body content", :query => { hash_of_params_here } ,:headers => {'Content-Type' => 'application/json', 'AuthKey' => "your_key_here"})
```

response object will have 'statuscode', 'headers', 'body' etc (whatever youtube send back in your case). You can access its content using

```
response.parsed_response
```

same for get requests too

Please do read more about it for better understanding before getting started.
Sources : [Documentation](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/httparty/HTTParty) & [Tutorial](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/its-time-to-httparty)

Answer (score 1):

Yuo can use [`excon`](https://github.com/excon/excon) gem to make specific `CRUD` or only `get` requests to external resources, for example, it should be something like this:

```
Excon.post('http://youtube.com', :body => 'token=sjdlsdjasdljsdlasjda')
```

**PS**: But seem you not requied the direct gems, tru useing `google-api` gem, as it described here in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/ruby).

Comment: And I would provide the authorization token by doing `Excon.get('http://geemus.com', :headers => {'Authorization' => 'Basic 0123456789ABCDEF'})`?

Comment: @Jill no, auth token you can get only with oauth google authentication

Comment: Yes I have the token, but how do I provide it for the request as it says in the instructions.

Comment: That google link is a little confusing. I can make more sense of excon.